# Open Materialize nested collapsible on active link based on path

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I've created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adburns/zLw256av/7/) with what I'm trying to achieve.   Basically, I am using the Collapsible component from  https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html  but trying to extend so that it is a nested collapsible.  Specifically, I am trying to open the collapsible on the right link depending on the URL path.

Open collapsible on active link depending on URL

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  var path = "some-folder/some-link2.aspx";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>WS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>WS M</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>WS P</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>WS S</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>HS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>SS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have.

The issue was that Collapsible doesn't have a refresh (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3771); therefore, you must re-instantiate it.

So, the only thing you needed to do is to find the parent bullets and add the class 'active', then instantiate Collapsible again to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  $('#btn').click(function(){    
    var path = "some-folder/some-link2.aspx";
    var selector = 'a[href="' + path + '"]';
    var links = $(selector);
    links.each(function(index){      
      var link = $(this).css({"color": "red"});     
      var parent = link.closest('ul.collapsible > li');
      parent.addClass('active');
      var grandparent = parent.parents('ul.collapsible > li');
      grandparent.addClass('active');
    });
    
    // Collapsible doesn't have a refresh. 
    // Just instantiate it again in order to work.
    $('.collapsible').collapsible()       
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Find URL" />

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>WS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>WS M</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>WS P</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>WS S</div>
          <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>HS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>SS</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is just what I was looking for!

I do have one problem though.

I have changed the code slightly so that the function is run page load.  I have also changed the path to this:

`var path = window.location.pathname;`  which returns the correct folder/page however a urls I have locally have varied relative directories so they either start with ../  or ../../  Any idea how I can get that working with the above?

Thanks again

@acarlstein

Comment: ok -  I have changed all links to the same relative level ../../ and added that to:

`var path = '../..' + window.location.pathname;`  and that seems to work.  

Thanks again

Comment: @Burns I am glad it helped you out. Don't forget to vote ;)